# How are dynamic memory networks employed in sequence to sequence modelling

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

Dynamic Memory networks are described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07285.pdf)
. I understand what is going on for question answering task but when it comes to sequence to sequence modeling, they describe it in 4th paragraph of 2.4 answer module.

> In the sequence modeling task, we wish to label each word
>   in the original sequence. To this end, the DMN is run in
>   the same way as above over the input words. For word t,
>   we replace Eq. 8 with $e^i = h^{i}_{t}$
>   . Note that the gates for the
>   first pass will be the same for each word, as the question is the same. This allows for speed-up in implementation
>   by computing these gates only once. However, gates for
>   subsequent passes will be different, as the episodes are different.

I could not understand how the global gates are computed and why would they be equal for each word for first pass. They are going to be computed as a function of question vector (same) and word vector (different for each word). This is how vague i am on what is going on here. Can somebody explain how the piece in the paragraph mentioned come together?